# MD5 java and mysql md5 match and look the same but aren't matching with .equals()

Tags: java, md5

Thanks for looking.  I'm having an issue with getting my database and connection to match passwords.  MySQL and my java md5s are the same, but when I check to see if it's equal in comparing, it says they're not the same.  I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

For example, here are the generated MD5's for both:
MySQL: 798da231909aa3645eced61dde9f9bfa
Java:  798da231909aa3645eced61dde9f9bfa

So, I'm not sure why they wouldn't be equal when I check.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 * Created by Ohlaph on 8/29/2015.
 */
public class Conn {

    private Connection con = null;
    private String JDBC = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String username = "root", password = "password";
    private Statement statement;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private String user_name, user_password;
    private String dbname = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/thon";

    public Conn(String user, String password) {
        this.user_name = user;
        this.user_password = MD5(password);

    }

    public void Connect() throws Exception {
        try {

            Class.forName(JDBC);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/thon", username, password);
            statement = con.createStatement();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }
    }//end CONNECT()

    public boolean checkIt() throws Exception {
        String check = "select * from users";

        try {
            rs = statement.executeQuery(check);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String usr = rs.getString("nickname");
                String pwd = rs.getString("password");

                System.out.println("user name " + usr + ", Password " + pwd);

                if (user_name.equals(usr) && user_password.equals(pwd)) {
                    System.out.println("Access Granted");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Access Denied");
                    return false;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        }
        con.close();
        return false;
    }//end checkIt()


    public static String MD5( String source ) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
            byte[] bytes = md.digest( source.getBytes("UTF-8") );
            return getString( bytes );
        } catch( Exception e )  {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }//end MD5()

    private static String getString( byte[] bytes ) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for( int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++ )
        {
            byte b = bytes[ i ];
            String hex = Integer.toHexString((int) 0x00FF & b);
            if (hex.length() == 1)
            {
                sb.append("0");
            }
            sb.append( hex );
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }// end getString()

}//end Conn.java
```

Comment: Btw, md5 is not a secure way to hash passwords. You should use sha, with a salt (a different one for each password)

Comment: Unrelated note: Why not add a where clause to the query instead of fetching all users?

Comment: That's a good question.  I will look into more advanced sql methods, as this is my first time dealing with java in a database before.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `user_password = MD5(user_password);` is *inside* the `while` loop, so it will MD5 the value on first user record, then MD5 the already MD5'd value on the second user record, and so on, so that by the time you get to the user in question you have a very mangled value.

Maybe it would be better to do the MD5 in the constructor.

---

Unrelated, but instead of querying the *entire* user table every time, you should use something like:

```
 String sql = "select password from users where nickname = ?";
```

and use a `PreparedStatement` to set the marker value (`?`).

---

**Update**

Your error is that you do the `System.out.println("Access Denied"); return false;` *inside* the loop, so the loop never gets to look at the second record.

Adding `where nickname = ?` to the SQL would help fix that, since only one record would be returned (assuming `nickname` is unique), but the loop logic is still flawed.

Comment: I changed the md5 to the constructor just to be safe, but still not working.  I have it print out the md5 password, and it matches my mysql generated one, but when I compare the two it won't match.  Strange.  I will look into the preparedstatement.